# datepicker in filters portion not show with created_at and updated_at fields using Active Admin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I'm using Active admin and datepicker in filters portion(index page) not show with created_at and updated_at fields. I search enough and not find solution in any place.

```
   filter :created_at ,:as => :date_picker   #not working
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

oh, god... it was easy

i found this

```
filter :created_at, :as => :date_range
```

around line `32` in file `.../activeadmin-0.6.2/lib/active_admin/filters/forms.rb`

Answer (score 0):

after configuring datetimepicker. It automatically works for filter.

For configure see below

```
   https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Combine-datetime-picker-with-active_admin
```